# SQL Server Trigger update column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

i need an example of basic sql trigger, now i explain:

I Have a table with 5 columns(column1, power, column3, column4, times)

the value of "power" change in real time (Are numbers), and his datatype is 'real'
while the datatype of "times" is 'int'

i would a trigger that everytime "power" go to 0 'times' increase by 1

sorry if my english isn't perfect! and hope you understood what i mean!if something isn't clear tell me and i will try to explain better! :)

Comment: A point of clarification: Your title has "MSSQL" but you have the "mysql" tag... which are you using?

Comment: Yeah, you're right sorry i wrong adding mysql tag maybe an typing error XD, btw i'm using mssql.

Answer (score 6):

A possible basic trigger:

```
create trigger MyBasicTrigger on MyBasicTable
after insert, update
as
--  Trigger rowcount should not mess with update that triggered it, search for it in documentation provided here
   set NoCount ON
-- If power is mentioned in update/insert statement at all
   if update(Power)
   begin
   -- Update times for each changed row that has value of power 0
   -- Inserted table holds new values in updated rows
   -- You didn't mention your PK column(s), so I assume the name would be "ID"
      update MyBasicTable set Times = Times + 1
      from MyBasicTable inner join inserted on MyBasicTable.ID = inserted.ID
      where Inserted.Power = 0
   end
```

Documentation for NoCount and update(power) is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx).

Comment: Thanks you Nikola, my primary key is column2 :)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming column1 is the primary key, the general form of the trigger is as follows:

```
create trigger MyPower
on MyTable
after insert, update
as
  if exists (select column1 
             from inserted i join MyTable m
             on i.column1 = m.column1
             and i.power = 0)
    update MyTable set times = times + 1 
    where exists (select column1 from inserted i 
              join MyTable m
              on i.column1 = m.column1)
```

Comment: Thanks you very much but 
"update MyTable set power = power + 1" shouldn't be 'set times = times +1' ?

Comment: Hate to bring bad news but count(*) always exists.

Comment: It's is never bad news when you learn something. Thanks Nikola I will correct!